# Why in the assembly Angular2 output error?

Tags: angular

I used the example in the angular documentation. But the example does not work when I perform the assembly through webpack. Why do these errors occur, and how should I fix them?

```
    $ webpack
    ts-loader: Using typescript@2.0.10 and /home/splincode/Develop/github.com/meetup/2016/november/3--angular2/tsconfig.json
    Hash: ca8d894606defc7a8ab3
    Version: webpack 1.13.3
    Time: 24164ms
           Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
       js/app.js    3.44 kB       0  [emitted]  app
    js/vendor.js    2.72 MB       1  [emitted]  vendor
      index.html  401 bytes          [emitted]  
        + 615 hidden modules

        ERROR in /home/splincode/Develop/github.com/meetup/2016/november/angular2/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts
(73,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'Require', but here has type 'NodeRequire'.

ERROR in ./source/js/components/app/app.module.ts
(4,55): error TS2339: Property 'decorate' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.

ERROR in ./source/js/components/app/app.module.ts
(4,92): error TS2339: Property 'decorate' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.

ERROR in ./source/js/components/app/app.module.ts
(14,5): error TS2364: Invalid left-hand side of assignment expression.

ERROR in ./source/js/components/app/app.component.ts
(4,55): error TS2339: Property 'decorate' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.

ERROR in ./source/js/components/app/app.component.ts
(4,92): error TS2339: Property 'decorate' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.

ERROR in ./source/js/components/app/app.component.ts
(15,5): error TS2364: Invalid left-hand side of assignment expression.

ERROR in [default] /home/splincode/Develop/github.com/meetup/2016/november/angular2/typings/globals/require/index.d.ts:387:12 
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A webpack starter for Angular",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "tslint": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

### tscongif.json

```
   {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

### my tree folder

```
.
├── config
│   └── webpack.dev.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── ************* more folder/files
├── package.json
├── readme.md
├── source
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       ├── components
│       │   └── app
│       │       ├── app.component.html
│       │       ├── app.component.ts
│       │       └── app.module.ts
│       ├── main.ts
│       └── vendor.ts
├── tsconfig.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

### webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'vendor': './source/js/vendor.ts',
    'app': './source/js/main.ts'
  },

  output: {
    path: './webapp/',
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts-loader', 'awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'source/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your package.json, you have installed 3 typings "@types/core-js", "@types/jasmine", "@types/node".
The thing is in tsconfig.json, you have specified like this

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       ...
       "types" : ["node"]
   }
}
```

This mean that when compiling, typescript only include "@types/node", and omit "@types/core-js", "@types/jasmine". So , just delete

```
"types" : ["node"]
```

Problem will be solved